# Unable to share an eclipse project to new GIT repo because resource already exists

Tags: eclipse, git

I have an eclipse workspace with two projects inside.  I added the first project to a new git repo parent/proj_1 and it created a .git folder inside of proj_1 and worked fine.  Next, I tried to add the second project to a new git repo parent/proj_2 and it created a .git folder inside of proj_2 and then errored with "Failed to initialize Git team provider,  Resource /proj_1 already exists"  Why is proj_1 an issue when adding proj_2 to a separate repo?  I tried creating a new repo outside of the parent folder and I receive the same error message

Comment: What exact git commands did you execute, in what folders? If you can show a command-line session, including the commands and the error message in context, that will answer a host of detailed questions and allow others to help you diagnose the problem.

Comment: The two projects existed in the workspace so I performed the following steps

Comment: 1. Right-click project proj_1 -> Team -> Share Project -> Create Repository C:\Users\Dropbox\home\git\proj_1 Finish -> Finish.  This was successful
2. Right-click project proj_2-> Team -> Share Project -> Create Repository C:\Users\Dropbox\home\git\proj_2 Finish.  This is when I received the Problem Occurred dialog stating that Resource /proj_1 already exists.